# Tratar uma coluna da mesma tabela duas vezes e apresentar como registro na mesma coluna

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Boa tarde Prezados,

Estou desenvolvendo um relatório com alguns padrões necessários, não irei me aprofundar sobre os padrões para a consulta, mas fato é que "consegui" fazer uma Query com os requisitos necessários através de concatenação, que ficou assim:

```
SELECT 
'0101010' + STUFF('000000000000000', 14-len(P.CODIGO_PESSOA), 14, P.CODIGO_PESSOA) + '    02'+STUFF('                                                  ',1,len(P.NOME), P.NOME) +'0701'+

'

0201010' + STUFF('000000000000000', 14-len(P.CODIGO_PESSOA), 14, 
P.CODIGO_PESSOA)  + '    0200103'+ @DT_ATUAL +'0933333'

From bd.PESSOAS P

Where P.CODIGO_PESSOA <> ''

order by 
P.NOME
```

Este relatório precisa ser exportado para um arquivo TXT e o resultado do banco de dados fica perfeito, pois apresenta as informações exatamente como preciso, necessitando apenas "copiar" para o TXT:

[image: Resultado_Consulta]

O problema ocorre pois como fiz através de concatenação, obviamente, o resultado das "duas linhas" (estou considerando o resultado após a quebra de linha como outra linha) estão no mesmo registro.

Quando levo esta Query para o report de nosso sistema, que só nos permite realizar a exportação de relatórios para o EXCEL fazendo com que ao copiar os dados da planilha exportada para um TXT, perde-se a quebra de linha, já que foi inserida através de "formatação".

O resultado que necessito é que a linha antes da quebra (+'0701'+

') seja um registro e a linha após a quebra seja outro registro, tudo na mesma "coluna", desta forma:

[image: Resultado_Desejado]

Isso é possível?

Desde já agradeço imensamente a atenção de todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fica aqui uma possível solução (pode ter algum erro de sintaxe, porque escrevi sem acesso ao SSMS).

```
DECLARE @DT_ATUAL VARCHAR = CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 104)

;WITH PESSOAS AS 
(
    SELECT 'Aaron John Doe' AS NOME,   '112' AS CODIGO_PESSOA UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Abigail Jane Doe' AS NOME, '222' AS CODIGO_PESSOA
),
RELATORIO AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY P.NOME) AS ROW_ID, 
            '0101010' + RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 15) + P.CODIGO_PESSOA, 15) + '    02' + LEFT(P.NOME + REPLICATE(' ', 50), 50) + '0701' AS LINHA1,
            '0201010' + RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 15) + P.CODIGO_PESSOA, 15) + '    0200103' + @DT_ATUAL + '0933333' AS LINHA2
       FROM PESSOAS P
      WHERE P.CODIGO_PESSOA <> ''
 )
 SELECT ROW_ID,
        LINHA1 AS REGISTO
   FROM RELATORIO 
  UNION ALL
 SELECT ROW_ID,
        LINHA2
   FROM RELATORIO
  ORDER BY 1, 2
```

O resultado é o seguinte:

```
ROW_ID  REGISTO
1       0101010000000000000112    02Aaron John Doe                                    0701
1       0201010000000000000112    020010300933333
2       0101010000000000000222    02Abigail Jane Doe                                  0701
2       0201010000000000000222    020010300933333
```

Fiz também algumas alterações que devem ajudar a tornar a query mais legível - substituição do `STUFF` pelo `RIGHT+REPLICATE ou LEFT+REPLICATE`

Deve dar para simplificar ainda mais, porque a única coisa que é preciso garantir é a ordem dos registos. A coluna `ROW_ID`, foi adicionada apenas para ajudar na ordenação, pode ser facilmente removida do resultado final.

Fica aqui outra alternativa, criando logo as duas linhas por registo. A `CTE Pessoas` é usada apenas para criar alguns dados de teste.

```
DECLARE @DT_ATUAL VARCHAR = CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 104)

;WITH PESSOAS AS 
(
    SELECT 'Aaron John Doe' AS NOME,   '112' AS CODIGO_PESSOA UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Abigail Jane Doe' AS NOME, '222' AS CODIGO_PESSOA
),
RELATORIO AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY P.NOME, P.CODIGO_PESSOA) AS ROW_ID, 
                '0101010' + RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 15) + P.CODIGO_PESSOA, 15) + '    02' + LEFT(P.NOME + REPLICATE(' ', 50), 50) + '0701' AS REGISTO
      FROM PESSOAS P
     WHERE P.CODIGO_PESSOA <> ''

    UNION ALL

    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY P.NOME, P.CODIGO_PESSOA) AS ROW_ID, 
                '0201010' + RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 15) + P.CODIGO_PESSOA, 15) + '    0200103' + @DT_ATUAL + '0933333'
      FROM PESSOAS P
     WHERE P.CODIGO_PESSOA <> ''
)
SELECT REGISTO
  FROM RELATORIO
 ORDER BY ROW_ID, REGISTO
```

O resultado, sem a coluna `ROW_ID` é

```
0101010000000000000112    02Aaron John Doe                                    0701
0201010000000000000112    020010300933333
0101010000000000000222    02Abigail Jane Doe                                  0701
0201010000000000000222    020010300933333
```

Comment: Sensacional Bruno! Ficou perfeito. Muito obrigado!

Comment: De  nada @OtávioAugusto